# How do you sort pairs in a list based on a nested value?

Tags: sorting, clojure

Given the following list in Clojure:

```
(def pairs '[(2,1),(3,2),(2,4)])
```

I want to sort these in descending order based on the second item in each pair.

ie I want them to sort into:

```
[(2,4),(3,2),(2,1)]
```

My question is: **How do you sort pairs in a list based on a nested value?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sort-by`:

```
(sort-by second > pairs)
```